# Are blocking diodes really needed for solar panels in parallel?

Tags: solar-cell, schottky

[image]If one connects two technically identical solar panels in parallel (to increase current), many sources suggest to put each of the panels in series with a Schottky diode before joining these branches together in parallel. The rationale behind this seems to be that one of the panels does not drive a current through the other panel in forward direction (hence the name "blocking diode", as opposed to the bypass diodes that are part of modern panels anyway).

But the only situation where I think this could be practically relevant is when one of the panels is significantly shaded relative to the other and both are left open-circuit. Because then the open-circuit voltage of the brighter panel exceeds the oc-voltage of the dimmer one and hence, some fraction of the current runs back into the dimmer panel. Since the magnitude of this current can never exceed the current that a single panel is short-circuiting onto itself in open-circuit mode, this cannot represent an overload situation. So, there is only some loss of efficiency (somehow similar to the problem of shaded panels in parallel), but not the risk of destruction.

On the other hand, if the panels are run closed-circuit (because that is what we have them for) and near to the maximum-power-point, the operating voltage is probably already significantly lower than the open-circuit voltage of both panels, and hence, the forward current that the blocking diode is supposed to suppress, is not possible (or rather it is negligible) anyway.

So my conclusion would be that the blocking Schottky diodes do nothing in most practical situations, and in some rather rare situations only save some residual efficiency, but do not influence panel lifetime (at least unless there is an exterior circuit failure, e.g. of the inverter, that puts forward voltage on the panels that massively exceeds the open-circuit voltage, but that would be a problem already for single panels or series connections, not only parallel connections).

Is that correct?

**PS:** according to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148607/solar-panels-at-night-without-diodes-short-circuit-or-source-of-power-dissipat?rq=1) topic, blocking diodes are recommended in general (independent of parallel or series arrangement of panels), in order for the battery not discharge over the panels. But I assume that everybody has a charge controller nowadays, which suppresses such situations. But even if it were necessary, why use several blocking diodes in parallel branches instead of just one? The only reason would be to avoid imbalance between panels, which is put into perspective by my introductory considerations.

Don't get me wrong, Schottky diodes are cheap, but I have aversions against unnecessarily complex designs.

Comment: I think you are right, but I don't have panels to test or confirm it. I hope an answer will arrive here. Can you determin an V/I profile for a dark panel using a current limited benchtop supply?

Comment: I don't have an adjustable supply. But what I have determined in the meantime are the compensation current of my panels, FYI. I have 6 string of 2 panels each. Each string has around 69 Volts and a nominal current of 14 Amps. The (open-loop) currents that compensate the slightly different gap voltages are only around 500 mA, which is ~35 Watts. This sounds significant, but distributed to the 4 m² of panel area this is only ~0.9 mW/cm², which is minute (also compared to the 800W total power of the string). My only concern now is, whether negative temperature coefficient can lead to instability.

Comment: Thank you for the update! Very interesting. I have read in a research report, that the assumption of equal distribution of this power may not be true, there may exist hot spots at very small low quality areas. An infra red picture might reveal this.

Comment: I have a thermal camera with tele lens. Tomorrow I will take a look if there are inhomogeneities (as far as this can be seen from the ground, under inclination). But I'm afraid the main issue is that problems might occur only under special conditions. I am already close to being paranoid enough for incorporating the Schottky diodes because they are a lot cheaper than new panels (and more accessible these days, possibly).

Answer (score 1):

I use blocking diodes on each string of four panels. I have seen panels catch on fire due to good panels providing current to the bad panel. I have eight strings each with a Schottky diode. Each string's current and voltage can be checked to determine if there is a failure in a panel or wiring.

Comment: Good point on that a panel can also be defective. Until now I only thought about lighted panels discharging over shaded ones. But I guess one panel being shorted due to damage is more realistic if there are no trees around. And, can be more severe, as your fire experience shows. I will now definitely hurry to update my arrangement with blocking diodes in order to eliminate the fire risk (even if panel short circuit might be a rare event).